# How to upgrade my version of GTK+2.0

Tags: upgrade, gtk

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/889019) affects me, but it says that it has been fixed in `gtk+2.0 - 2.24.8-0ubuntu1`. I have version `2.24.6-0ubuntu5`. Is there some way for me to upgrade?

(Ubuntu 11.10 64bit unity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backport the version of GTK+ 2.0 that is in 12.04 to 11.10, or ask that the fix be SRUed to 11.10 as well, on the bug report itself. You probably should have just asked directly on the bug report, rather than on here.

Comment: I guess the problem is that I don't know how to "Backport the version of GTK+ 2.0 that is in 12.04" - but thanks for giving me more information to search for.